# Audio through HDMI with Nvidia Optimus

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi, nvidia-optimus

HDMI Audio with Nvidia dedicated video card just doesn't work, although it have had. After the upgrade from 20.04 LTS to 22.10 (by reinstalling) the HDMI sound device is detected, but there are no profiles (see picture). To be honest, the audio through HDMI only ever worked on 20.04 LTS, with Ubuntu-based distros being the only ones that made it work. The case seems to be pretty rare, although reproducible - people are reporting it. Anyone found a sane solution?

Laptop: HP Omen 15

Kubuntu 22.10 (Kernel 5.19.0)

Nvidia proprietary driver 515.65 (although no matter what I use, it doesn't work)

[My settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjVvr.png)